# Accessing a random element of an arraylist yields the same results

Tags: java, list

I have a class called Keypoints and i want to create an array list storing various keypoints objects.
This is how i decalred and initialise the Keypoints list:

```
    private static List<Keypoint> m_keyPoints = new ArrayList<Keypoint>();
```

so in my codes , i have a for loop which adds keypoints objects into the list :

```
            for(xi=0;xi<width;xi++)
            {
                for(yi=0;yi<height;yi++)
                {
                    /*Calculation for scale,mag,orien*/

                        // Save this keypoint into the list
                        Keypoint kp =new Keypoint(xi*scale/2, yi*scale/2, mag, orien, i*m_numIntervals+j-1);
                        m_keyPoints.add(kp);
                }
            }
```

But now whenever i try to access a random element from the list , I'm always getting the same results .

```
    for(int ikp = 0;ikp<m_numKeypoints;ikp++)
    {
        Keypoint key =m_keyPoints.get(ikp);
        int scale = key.s();
        float kpxi = key.xi();
        float kpyi = key.yi();
    }
```

I'm am getting the same value for scale,kpxi, and kpyi for every element in the list even though I'm very sure that every value is different. Instead it's returning the last object in the list . 
So my question is , am I doing it wrongly when it comes to adding the object into the list or is it a problem with my keypoint class ? or is it something else altogether  ?

Below is the class for Keypoint

```
import java.util.List;
public class Keypoint {
public float            xi;
public float            yi; 
public List<Double> orien ;
public List<Double> mag;
public  int scale;  

public Keypoint(){}

public Keypoint(float x, float y, List<Double> magnitude, List<Double> orientation, int s)
{
    xi = x;
    yi = y;
    mag = magnitude;
    orien = orientation;
    scale = s;
}
public static float xi()
{
    return xi;
}
public static float yi()
{
    return yi;
}
public static int s()
{
    return scale;
}
public  static List<Double> mag()
{
    return mag;
}
public  static List<Double> orien()
{
    return mag;
}
```

}

Comment: Show us the adding loop

Comment: @baraky It's just a for loop which loops through xi and yi to perfrom calculation for the various parameters for the Keypoint constructor

Comment: How can you have static getter for a non static field?

Comment: @KorayTugay: You can't. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you show doesn't compile. However, the errors hint at what is going wrong in your *actual* code.

All the getters of `Keypoint` are `static`:

```
public static float xi() { return xi; }
public static float yi() { ... }
public static int s()    { ... }
...
```

This could only compile if the corresponding data members would also be `static`, which means they're shared by all instances of the class.

Comment: I've removed the static keyword from the Keypoint class but I'm still getting the same results .

Comment: @user1926691: Please show us your *actual* code and not some approximation thereof.

Comment: added code . I'm using JavaCV , and I'm currently trying to translate a OpenCV C++ code into java.  But the problem I'm facing now is not related to this at all as I'm sure that it is a problem with my usage of the list class

Comment: @user1926691: I still don't understand why you wouldn't show us your *actual* code. The code that, you know, *compiles*.

Comment: It's ok, Thanks to your hint , I've fixed the problem already . It was indeed the problem with the static and non- static thing.I did not remove the static keyword when declaring the variables in the Keypoint class. I removed it when i posted my question but forgot to make the corressponding changes to my own code . 

I wouldn't show my code because it is over 600 lines long and I'm still in the midst of translating it from C++ . Anyway thanks a lot for your help.